# C++ Template Class Compare

Tags: c++, templates

I have recently got into templates in C++, and I wondered if I could use it for this purpose; let's say I have a function called Swap.

```
template<typename T>
void Swap(T class)
{
  ...
}
```

and Class C1 and C2, and I would want something like Swap(c1); which would make the return of the function a new c2 and vice versa. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please make an attempt. You may find your attempt is good enough. If not, from this attempt we can infer how close you are to accomplishing your goals and perhaps what your goals actually are.

Answer (score 0):

No need of template, 2 overloads suffice:

```
C2 Swap(const C1& c1) { return C2{/*...*/}; }
C1 Swap(const C2& c2) { return C1{/*...*/}; }
```